# how to preserve obfuscate interface parameters inside android AAR module

Tags: android, module, proguard, aar

I have the following code

```
public class MyClass { 


    public interface MyInterface { 
           void addUser(String name , String family );
           void getUser(Integer userId);
    } 
}
```

when i compiling it to AAR Library and  importing in another project , parameters in interface will be obfuscate like this :

```
MyClass.Myinterface interface = new Myclass.Myinterface() {

 @Override
 public void addUser(String s , String s1){

 }

 @Override
 public void getUser(Interger i){

 }
```

is there any solution ? i tried disabling pro-guard ,   but didn't success .  also tries disabling  obfuscate in pro-guard

```
  -dontobfuscate
  -optimizations !code/allocation/variable
  -keep public class * {
       public protected * ;
   }
```

any solution ?

Comment: you could try to add the `-g` argument to your javac call

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

To keep only the names of parameters in your library, you can use the following ProGuard option:

```
-keepparameternames
```